# Debian server is showing PHP code instead of interpreting it

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, apache-2.4, vagrant

I was told on stackoverflow to post this question here:

**Scroll down to see result of things I've done based on suggestions**

I am setting up my first project using Vagrant. I chose the following package `puppetlabs/debian-7.8-64-puppet` for the debian server, because it's the same we are using for our remote development server. Unfortunetely this debian distro only contains the PHP version 5.4, so I tried to install dotdeb so I can use PHP 5.6.11.

I added

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

as mentioned here https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/ to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then ran the following commands

```
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg

## get package list from sources incl. new set source dotdeb
sudo apt-get update

## Install php, APC, gd and cURL
sudo apt-get install -y php5 php5-apcu php5-gd php5-curl
```

Now, when using `php --version` it tells me that I'm using version 5.6.11, so it seems to have worked to install it. But the problem I'm having is, that the webserver doesn't seem to interpret it because it displays the real php code. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `Vagrantfile` without the commentes

```
config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/debian-7.8-64-puppet"
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant_ressources/bootstrap.sh"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"
```

And this is my `bootstrap.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Use single quotes instead of double quotes to make it work with special-character passwords
PASSWORD='12345678'

# Update package manager
apt-get update
# Install apache2
sudo apt-get install -y apache2

# Add dotdeb to packages
if [ ! -f /var/log/dotdebconfig ];
then
echo "" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "#dotdeb" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg

## get package list from sources incl. new set source dotdeb
sudo apt-get update

## Install php, APC, gd and cURL
sudo apt-get install -y php5 php5-apcu php5-gd php5-curl

touch /var/log/dotdebconfig

fi

#install mysql and give password to installer
if [ ! -f /var/log/mysqlconfig ];
then
# Set passwords
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $PASSWORD"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $PASSWORD"
# Install MySQL Server and cURL
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
sudo apt-get -y install php5-mysql

touch /var/log/mysqlconfig

fi

if [ ! -f /var/log/XXXXXX ];
then
    mkdir -p /var/www/htdocs
    # Install XXXXXX vhost
    sudo a2dissite default
    sudo a2enmod rewrite
    cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
    # copy default vhost conf to sites-available
    sudo cp /var/www/vagrant_ressources/XXXXXX.vhost.conf XXXXXX.dev
    sudo a2ensite XXXXXX.dev
    touch /var/log/XXXXXX
fi

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And this is my XXXXXX.vhost.conf (don't know if its needed)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/htdocs/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Suggestions**

Someone told me: "Try installing libapache2-mod-php5"
However, it seems like it's already on my server, because I'm getting the following error message: `libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

Check if php is added to apache configuration.

At least you have to have a line similar to this in your apache conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

and or a line like this:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

If it's the problem, you have to add:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

There are some more extra parameters you may tune, full documentation oh how to is here: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

If it's everything in place and still not working, then take a look on if you have the php module installed by issuing `dpkg -l |grep mod-php`
Try maybe to reinstall removing it with `purge` and installing it again